# React Native Firebase Auth - 'Native module cannot be null'

Tags: firebase, react-native

After installing [react-native-firebase-auth](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage) to my react-native ejected app,

When trying to access the "auth" module:

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
```

I received the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed Xcode create a second app instance on my device during the build process.

Removing both instances from the device and rebuilding resolved this error.